# Unable to mount NTFS volume in nautilus, windows 8 full shutdown enabled

Tags: dual-boot, mount, shutdown, ntfs, hibernate

In Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, I cannot mount my NTFS drive. I have turned off fast startup/shutdown in windows, only to be faced with this error regardless of what I do -

> `Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/eric/Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS amd64:
>   Command-line mount -t "ntfs" -o
>   "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177"
>   "/dev/sdb2" "/media/eric/Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS amd64"' exited with
>   non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
>   Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Operation not permitted The NTFS
>   partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows
>   fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
>   read-only with the 'ro' mount option.`

I'm not sure what to do at this point, as `$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb2` yields

> `$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb2 Mounting volume... Windows is hibernated,
>   refused to mount. FAILED Attempting to correct errors...  Processing
>   $MFT and $MFTMirr... Reading $MFT... OK Reading $MFTMirr... OK
>   Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr
>   completed successfully. Setting required flags on partition... OK
>   Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK Windows is hibernated,
>   refused to mount. Remount failed: Operation not permitted`

Is this a windows problem, or an Ubuntu one?
Even restarting windows or using
`C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe -f -s -t 00`
Doesn't yield positive results.

Comment: did you try disabling hibernation completely by running `powercfg /h off` as administrator in windows and see if solves the issue?

Comment: Haha! I've tried many other solutions, but this is the one that did it for me! Thank you! Please add as an answer and I will +1 and accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling hibernation completely by running `powercfg /h off` as administrator in windows. Happy that this solved the issue for you!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and what I do is to "reboot" windows, and then choose ubuntu from the grub menu. Then I can mount windows partitions with no problem.

My theory is that windows hibernates when you choose "shut down". Another one of those misleading/lying windows actions. Now I just never "shut down" windows, I always reboot into a linux distro, and then I shut down the computer from the linux distro (or just from the grub menu). Then, whenever I boot linux again (which is what I use most of the time), I have no problem mounting the windows root partition--or any other.

Comment: I need to mount the drive so I can install grub across both drives.